# Use template from DB in usermailer and interpret ruby code inside the string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, mongodb, actionmailer

Ok so this one is hurting my brain:

I have something like this in send_invoice_html.erb which is one of my user_mailer views:

```
<% if @cust_inv_template %>
<%=raw @cust_inv_template.cust_mail_invoice_template%>
<%else%>
```

So I have the user setup their email template inside another view, save that to the database, and then I want to say "if there is a template, use that, else, use my default".

Inside my template is some HTML and some Rails code:

```
<html>
Aloha <%= @user.first_name %>,<br />

<p>Please find attached your invoice for Job #<%= @job.job_number %> which we completed on <% ed = Date.parse(@job.end_date.to_s); 
    endDate = Date.strptime(ed.to_s, "%m-%d-%Y") %><%= endDate.to_s %>.</p>
<p>If you have any questions, please call us at <%= number_to_phone(@admin.phone_number) %> or email us at <%= @admin.email %></p>

<br />Thanks,

<br/><%= @admin.name %>
</html>
```

So when the message gets sent to my mailbox (Gmail) - I see :

```
Aloha <%= @user.first_name %>,
Please find attached your invoice for Job #<%= @job.job_number %> which we completed on <% ed = Date.parse(@job.end_date.to_s); endDate = Date.strptime(ed.to_s, "%m-%d-%Y") %><%= endDate.to_s %>.

If you have any questions, please call us at <%= number_to_phone(@admin.phone_number) %> or email us at <%= @admin.email %>

TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST


Thanks, 
<%= @admin.name %>
```

Ergo - my HTML is being respected just fine with the <%=raw part (I tried html_safe previously) - but the Rails code is being spit out as-is.  I want that Rails-y goodness to be interpreted BEFORE the message is sent.

When I take out the if else stuff and just use the *exact same template* the Rails code IS respected.

Which means there has to be some kind of "spit out what's inside this string var AND if there's any cool rails stuff in there go ahead and interpret that" method in some class :)

Anyone know what that is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`raw` is about not escaping the HTML, but it will not interpret your ruby code. To interpret your ruby code you need to use evaluate the erb template.

```
<%=raw Erb.new(@cust_inv_template.cust_mail_invoice_template).result %>
```

[Check the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html) for more info.

Comment: undefined method `first_name' for nil:NilClass  <-- It's definitely trying to evaluate the ruby code in the string now - but it's not inheriting the variables from the controller as it should...

Comment: I got it working by adding (binding) to your string in order to make my variables available to ERB within that scope!

Comment: @notaceo I was not online any longer, great thing you end up finding by yourself :-)